Address passed to thirdweb is not getting passed correctly
I'm building a smart wallet that is ERC 4337 compatible, for that I'm using the thirdweb accountfactory contract. Now when creating a smart wallet I'm passing the address of the account factory contract
  export function createSmartWallet(): SmartWallet {
    const smartWallet = new SmartWallet({
        chain: PolygonAmoyTestnet,
        factoryAddress: "0x2622008A23078433d9e63943094260fe483121XX",//for privacy reasons XX has been added 
        gasless: true,
        clientId: CLIID, //process.env.CLIID,
    });
    return smartWallet;
};

Now when login in to the console of google chrome I'm getting an
login.tsx:21 Error: Could not fetch bytecode for contract at 0xE56484359d72d4C45897999C9D1aC2ED802d5e9e on chain 80002, double check that the address and chainId are correct.
    at fetchContractMetadataFromAddress (contract-publisher-1ff1fe07.browser.esm.js:5270:11)
    at async ThirdwebSDK.getContract (sdk-33cc295e.browser.esm.js:2051:26)
    at async connectSmartWallet (wallet.ts:50:33)
    at async connectWallet (login.tsx:15:28)

As you can see the address that I'm passing and the address the is being passed are entirely different. I don't know why this is happening, can anyone please help me find out what the cause behind this error is.
